# Javascript in yii2 is not responding

Tags: javascript, php, yii, yii2

I'm a new yii develeper.
I want to list my database and then put a button beside all of my elements and then when clinet click on button, the computer show me all details.
Here is my view file :

```
<h1> پایگاه داده ما </h1>
<script>
    function showUser(Id) {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (Id == 0) {
            document.getElementById("showmore").innerHTML = "Test";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            //  IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari   کد لازم براي مرورگر هاي جديد
            document.getElementById("showmore").innerHTML = "Test2";
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        }
        else
        {
            //  IE6, IE5         کد براي مرورگرهاي قديمي
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function  ( )
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {

                document.getElementById("showmore").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "localhost/datils.php?q=" + Id, true);
        xmlhttp.send ( );
    }
</script>
<style>
    span
    {
        color: white;
    }

</style>
<?php
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;
echo '<br>';
foreach($show as $k =>$v)
{

$Id= $v['id'];
//$Id=0;
    echo $Id.".";
    echo $v ['countryName'];
    echo '<ul>';

    echo '<li> پایتخت :';
    echo $v ['capital'];
    echo '</li>';

    echo '<li>'.'جمعیت :';
    echo '<span >i</span>'.(string)$v['population'];

    echo '</li>';

    echo '</ul>';
    echo "<button value=$Id , onclick=showUser(this.value)>More</button>";
    echo "<div id=showmore>   </div>" ;
    echo '<hr>';
}
echo LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination'=>$page
]);
?>
```

And here is my datils.php file:

```
<?php


   $q=$_GET["q"];    


   //   این دستور مقدار پارامتر ارسالی از دستور ای جکس را دریافت می کند

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root" , '' ,'mydatabase1');             // ایج اد ارتباط با پایگاه داده مورد نظر   



    if ($con->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
    } 


    $sql="SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id = '".$q."'";              //    q    دریافت اطلاعات از جدول مورد نظر بر مبنای پارامتر 


    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);           //         result     ریختن نتیجه عملیات انتخاب اطلاعات از پایگاه داده در متغیر


    echo "<table border='1'>
         <tr>
              <th>countryName</th>
              <th>currencyCode</th>
              <th>population</th>
         </tr>";

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))           //    ساخت جدول در خروجی با نتیجه دریافتی از پایگاه داده
          {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['countryName'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['currencyCode'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['population'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
           }
      echo "</table>";

      mysqli_close($con);   /* //       قطع ارتباط با پایگاه داده*/
?>
```

My problem is this is not working! The line

```
 document.getElementById("showmore").innerHTML = "Test2";
```

works fine and that means my function is working but it doesn't respond.

nse from details.php.
Please guide me !

Answer (score 0):

Few corrections need to be in your view file:

**1.** Instead of

```
echo "<button value=$Id , onclick=showUser(this.value)>More</button>";
```

use

```
echo "<button value='$Id' onclick='javascript:showUser(this.value)'>More</button>";
```

**2.** Instead of

```
xmlhttp.send ( );
```

it should be

```
xmlhttp.send();
```